# Conditional probability question about students owning cars and bikes

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> At a university $0.15$ students have a car on campus. The likelihood of students having both a car and a bike on campus is $0.03$. If a student has a car on campus, what is the probability that they also have a bike on campus?

Comment: I rather doubt that $0.15$ students have much of anything. I suspect that you mean that $0.15$ is the fraction of the student body having a car on campus, or the probability that a randomly selected student has a car on campus.

Comment: They will certainly have a cellphone for their texting, no matter how much or little have :)  Your hint was exactly what I was thinking off. Time for an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Imagine for a moment that there are $1000$ students. $150$ of them have a car on campus. How many have both a car and a bike on campus? What fraction of those with cars is this?

Now carry out the same analysis with an unspecified number $n$ of students.

Answer (score 1):

$0.15$ of the students have a car. $0.03$ have a car and a bike. This means $0.12$ have a car but not a bike. Now you want the probability that they have a bike given that they have a car.

That would be:

$$\mathbb{P}\{B|C\}=\frac{\mathbb{P}\{C,B\}}{\mathbb{P}\{C\}}=\frac{0.03}{0.15}=0.2$$

Answer (score 0):

If there are $100$ students in the campus, $15$ have a car and $3$ have both a car and a bike.
Now, if I lie in the $15$ students batch, that means that $3$ of us must have both.
The probability of each one of us having a bike is equal.

So according to me it must be $1/15$.

Comment: I don't see how you get from three students out of fifteen having both to a chance of $\frac 1{15}$

Comment: What I mean to say @RossMillikan that imagine that you have a car (you are one of the 15 students) and this also means that 3 people in the group (including you) have a bike too. The probability from this perspective that you have a bike is 1/15.

Comment: It is not about you, it is about a randomly selected one of the 15.  If three of them have bikes, it is 3/15 that the chosen one has a bike.

Comment: Doesnt he mean that out of 15, what is probability that i have a bike?

Comment: Also he also might mean that 15 people have have a car and 3 more with a car and they have a bike too. 18in total have a car.